# Conditional cell fill code to apply to several rows with different conditions for each row

Tags: excel, logic, vba

I am trying to write a conditional cell fill code using VBA but am having some syntax issues. I realize there is a tab for this, but I need to apply the code to several different rows with different conditions for each row so code would be faster for my purposes. I am pretty new to VBA but I think I got the logic correct at least.

Basically there is a lead column with the value that each value in the following columns needs to be tested against.

```
(TEST VALUE) | (VALUE TO BE TESTED)| (VALUE TO BE TESTED)...

(TEST VALUE) | (VALUE TO BE TESTED)| (VALUE TO BE TESTED)...
```

If the value is greater then or less than the test value by 3 units the cell needs to turn red, otherwise it needs to be green.

Here is what I did. I used a button macro but if there is a way to automatically do this without a button that'd be best.

I keep getting *run time error "1004" ; application or object defined error* on line five. So basically I am using a nested set of for loops. The first loop selects the row and picks the test value for that row. Maybe I am assigning the variable wrong or I need to select the worksheet I am working in? The next part of the loop tests the following values in each row to see if they are inside or outside the specified range of the test value. Lastly the cell is colored based on this determination.

CODE:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, T As Integer, R As Integer
'T is the cell we want to test, R is the Integer we want to use to test T
For i = 6 To 132
R = Cells(6, j).Value
For j = 4 To 1000 'loop through each column to test each cell (move to the right down selected row)
  T = Cells(i, j).Value 'test each cell
  If T < (R - 3) Or T > (R + 3) Then
    Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
    Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorInex = 3
End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

I also tried using the cell formula editor to apply this code but I don't believe you can change cell color this way:

```
"=IF(OR(D6<$C$6-3,D6>$C$6+3),"CHANGE COLOR TO RED","CHANGE COLOR TO GREEN""
```

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to something meaningful. You've included Excel and VBA in your tags, and they're not needed in the subject. Removing them leaves *coding question*, which of course is obvious (if you didn't have a coding question, you wouldn't be posting on a Q&A site). Your question should describe the problem you're having or the question you're asking us to answer, in a way that will have meaning to future users here who find it in a search result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following line down one line (It's before you assigned a value to J):

```
R = Cells(6, j).Value
```

Comment: Okay I just needed to change j to i because I meant to loop through the rows not columns. I am now getting an error on:   " T = Cells(i, j).Value 'test each cell " saying runtime error 13, type mismatch. what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't need to use vba.  Just use conditional formatting. On the tabs, assuming you're using excel 2007 or above go to the home tab and select conditional formatting.  Select something from the options or you can select new rule.  From the pop up select "use a formula to determine which cells to format".  Enter the equation something like "=if($a$3<=a4+3,TRUE,False)" then select the formatting you want.